# Facebook Graph API - granting access token to every user to view public photos

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm having this annoying trouble with allowing users to view public albums/photos on our Facebook page through our app.

Something like this: http://www.cosmiccocktails.com.au/pages/gallery-of-events.html. You can see that this website loads up all the Facebook photos on their page correctly without asking users to sign in or anything.

However, on my app, using Hello.js, I can't seem to replicate that feature. I always get the access token error but not sure how to grant it to every user coming to the site.

The code that I use to connect to the Facebook App is

```
hello.init({
        facebook: 63492627xxxxxxx // my app ID
    }, {
        scope: "files, photos",
        redirect_uri: window.location.href,
    });

hello.api('facebook:225216104178294/albums?fields=name,count,picture,type', function(r){
    if (!r || r.error) {
        console.log("Failed - Access Token not granted");
        return false;
    }
    console.log('Succeeded');
});
```

Which always returns false due to the acccess token error.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: 1. ) The scopes files and photos aren't valid scopes. 2.) You don't need user_photos scope to read a public pages photos. 3. ) Is hello.api being called before the user has been successfully validated by Facebook?